# Run playbook against Openstack with Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-tower

I am trying to run a simple playbook against Openstack in admin tenant using Ansible Tower, both running on localhost. Here is the script:

```
--- # 
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local 
  tasks:
  - name: Security Group
    os_security_group:
      state: present
      name: example
```

I have done the following configuration:

- Credentials:

[image]

- Template:

[image]

- Inventory test:

[image]

With this configuration, I am getting this error:

```
TASK [Security Group] **********************************************************
13:35:48
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Any idea what can be? Looks like is a credential problem.

Answer (score 0):

Untick `Enable Privilege Escalation` - it's not necessary. Your OpenStack privilege/authorisation will be tied to your OpenStack credentials (admin in this case), not the user running the Ansible task.